# apns-collapse-id option not working in FCM

Tags: apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement APNS notification where i want to maintain single latest notification for all my incoming notification. 
 I'm using `apns-collapse-id` which should be supported by FCM as described here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages

However when i send multiple notification with single collapse-id the end use is still getting multiple notification

Below is the receiver end payload, which has  `"gcm.notification.apns-collapse-id"` which i'm guessing is being sent by google.

I'm trying to understand if i need to make any changes to make it work.

Original Sender Payload:

```
{ 
"to" : "xyz",
"notification": {
    "title" : "title_here",
    "body" : "body_here",
},
"data" : {
    "message" : "Message_Here"
},
"apns-collapse-id" : "STRING_ID_HERE"
"content_available" : true
}
```

Receiver side Payload:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "body_Here";
            title = "title_here";
        };
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = "0:123456789ae";
    "gcm.notification.apns-collapse-id" = STRING_ID_HERE;
    "google.c.a.e" = 1;
    message = "Message_Here";
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue have you resolved it?

Comment: I resigned at that organization and changed my industry and moved to a different part of the country, Hope you find a better way to resolve this issue.

Comment: It looks like an iOS bug to me, because when I swipe left to delete one of the duplicated notification from iOS Notification Center, the another one disappeared as well. So the iOS is actually identified them as the same notification.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the latest `send` function from the `firebase-admin` lib, usage described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#customize-messages-across-platforms).

It seems to work fine.